# How to count the number of unique values by group?

Tags: r

```
ID= c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
color=c('white', 'green', 'orange', 'white', 'green', 'green')

d = data.frame (ID, color)
```

My desired result is

```
unique_colors=c(3,3,3,2,2,2)
d = data.frame (ID, color, unique_colors)
```

or more clear in a new dataframe c

```
ID= c('A','B')
unique_colors=c(3,2)
c = data.frame (ID,unique_colors)
```

I've tried different combinations of `aggregate` and `ave` as well as `by` and `with` and I suppose it is a combination of those functions.

The solution would include:

```
length(unique(d$color))
```

to calculate the number of unique elements.

Comment: See also [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421776/how-to-add-count-of-unique-values-by-group-to-r-data-frame/17421925#17421925), (somewhat similar title on that Q...did you search before posting?) for additional possibilities

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I think you've got it all wrong here. There is no need neither in `plyr` or `<-` when using `data.table`.

Recent versions of *data.table*, v >= 1.9.6, have a new function `uniqueN()` just for that.

```
library(data.table) ## >= v1.9.6
setDT(d)[, .(count = uniqueN(color)), by = ID]
#    ID count
# 1:  A     3
# 2:  B     2
```

If you want to create a new column with the counts, use the `:=` operator

```
setDT(d)[, count := uniqueN(color), by = ID]
```

---

Or with `dplyr` use the `n_distinct` function

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(color))
# Source: local data table [2 x 2]
# 
#   ID count
# 1  A     3
# 2  B     2
```

Or (if you want a new column) use `mutate` instead of `summary`

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n_distinct(color))
```

Comment: And a poor man's function would be `with(d, ave(as.numeric(color), ID, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))`

Comment: @akrun you can probably post this as an alternative.

Comment: @DavidArenburg David, Maybe In missing something obvious, but I am trying to use uniqueN with the most recent version of data.table and it is saying that the package does not exist.  You have any ideas

Comment: @MatthewR yes, as I mentioned, this function present only in the development version on GitHub. Please follow the link I provided.

Comment: This also works:
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n())