# R language - count of multiple columns group by one column

Tags: r, distinct-values

I got data frame in R that looks like this:

```
> df
   c1 c2 c3
1: 10 c1 i1
2: 10 c1 i2
3: 10 c1 i3
4: 10 c2 i1
5: 10 c2 i2
6: 10 c2 i3
7: 20 c11 i1
8: 20 c11 i2
9: 20 c11 i3
10: 20 c12 i1
11: 20 c12 i2
12: 20 c12 i3
```

I need to sum distinct counts of columns c2 and c3 group by c1 - to get the following result:

```
10 2 3
20 2 3
```

How would I get that done in R?

Thanks

Comment: .. the row count is not very large (thousands perhaps) so performance is not the issue ...

Comment: I am getting an error running this:

Comment: > df
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      c1    c2    c3
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     10    c1    i1
2     10    c1    i2
3     10    c1    i3
4     10    c2    i1
5     10    c2    i2
6     10    c2    i3
7     20   c11    i1
8     20   c11    i2
9     20   c11    i3
10    20   c12    i1
11    20   c12    i2
12    20   c12    i3
> df[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), by=c1, .SDcols=c("c2","c3")] 
Error in `[.tbl_df`(df, , lapply(.SD, uniqueN), by = c1, .SDcols = c("c2",  : 
  unused arguments (by = c1, .SDcols = c("c2", "c3"))

Comment: .. df is a data frame in this case

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173677/r-how-to-count-the-number-of-unique-values-by-group/28173835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `base R` `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(c2,c3)~c1, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))


#  c1 c2 c3
#1 10  2  3
#2 20  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

As the OP's dataset looks like a `data.table`, we can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)` - if it is a 'data.frame'), grouped by 'c1', we loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and find the `length` of `unique` elements (`uniqueN`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), by= c1]
#   c1 c2 c3
#1: 10  2  3
#2: 20  2  3
```

Comment: thanks for both answers; in either case - if I want some column to be the count of different values (like above) and for some other to be sum of the values( for numeric columns) - basically two different functions applied to two different subset of columns - with the same group by one column as above, would that be possible in one line?

Comment: @ZoranKrunic  Yes, it is possible, `setDT(df1)[, c(lapply(.SD[, names1vec, with = FALSE], uniqueN), lapply(.SD[, names2vec, with = FALSE], sum)), by = c1]`