# Performance of group_by on factor columns

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I have a serious performance issue with a rather easy operation. In fact, I don't get any result at all, even after several hours of running the code.

My data frame consists of approximately 400k records of 10 variables. The code for the operation is:

```
a2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(X1,X2,X3,X4) %>% 
  summarise(a = length(unique(ID)))
```

Where X1-X4 are all factors (1600 - 5600 levels). Could the issue be that my ID variable is also a factor (184573 levels)? If so, how can I fix this? I used similar code for a data frame where ID was a int and that worked fine.

However, with my current dataset changing to `int` is not possible and changing to `chr` does not seem to make sense. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: try to solve it with `data.table` and don't use factors.

Comment: Could you provide example data, `dput(head(dat))` or just `head(dat)` if too many factors?  Yes, I would keep IDs as int or char, not factor.

Comment: Also, try using  `a = n_distinct(ID)` instead of `a = length(unique(ID))`.

Comment: Relevant post, to see other package options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840294/counting-unique-distinct-values-by-group-in-a-data-frame

Comment: On my aging PC it took 1.211559 seconds (median), timed with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark`, data.frame of the size in the question, using `a = n_distinct(ID)`.